# update many to many records with postgresql / plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a web based system that has several tables (postgres/pgsql) that hold many to many relationships such as;
table x
column_id1 smallint FK
column_id2 smallint FK

In this scenario the update is made based on column_id2

At first to update these records we would run the following function;

```
-- edited to protect the innocent
CREATE FUNCTION associate_id1_with_id2(integer[], integer) RETURNS integer
AS $_$
DECLARE
    a alias for $1;
    b alias for $2;
    i integer;
BEGIN
    delete from tablex where user_id = b;
    FOR i IN array_lower(a,1) .. array_upper(a,1) LOOP
        INSERT INTO tablex (
            column_id2,
            column_id1)
        VALUES (
            b,
            a[i]);
    end loop;
RETURN i;
END;
$_$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

that seemed sloppy and now with the addition of auditing it really shows.

What I am trying to do now is only delete and insert the necessary rows.

I have been trying various forms of the following with no luck

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION associate_id1_with_id2(integer[], integer) RETURNS integer
AS $_$
DECLARE
    a alias for $1;
    b alias for $2;
c varchar;
    i integer;
BEGIN
    c = array_to_string($1,',');

    INSERT INTO tablex (
            column_id2,
            column_id1)
            (
    SELECT column_id2, column_id1
    FROM tablex
            WHERE column_id2 = b
    AND column_id1 NOT IN (c)
    );

    DELETE FROM tablex
    WHERE column_id2 = b
    AND column_id1 NOT IN (c);

RETURN i;
END;
$_$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

depending on the version of the function I'm attempting there are various errors such as explicit type casts (i'm guessing it doesnt like c being varchar?) for the current version.

first off, is my approach correct or is there a more elegant solution given there are a couple tables which this type of handling is required?  If not could you please point me in the right direction?

if this is the right approach could you please assist with the array conversion for the NOT IN portion of the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `array_to_string`, use `unnest` to transform the array into a set of rows (as if it was a table), and the problem can be solved with vanilla SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tablex(column_id1,column_id2)
 select ai,b from unnest(a) as ai where not exists
  (select 1 from tablex where column_id1=ai and column_id2=b);

DELETE FROM tablex
where column_id2=b and column_id1 not in
  (select ai from unnest(a) as ai);
```